# Deploying SSAS cube with no changes requires reprocess

Tags: tfs, ssas

I have an Analysis Services Cube in TEST and PROD.
We have recently started using branches in TFS.

After our development sprint and deployments, we will restore a backup of PROD over TEST, with the cubes coming through in their processed state.

However, recently, if we deploy the exact same project back to TEST (so exact same schema as what is deployed), all cubes become unprocessed.

I don't think it ever used to do this. For example, we tried changing a translation, not expecting to have to reprocess the cube and found that the whole thing required processing (which takes many hours).

Any idea why? It feels like SSAS is thinking that this is a new database and recreating it (although the created timestamps on the database are still from many months ago)

Steps to reproduce:
1. Create new branch called 'Branch A' from the master branch (master branch is currently deployed to our Analysis Server).
2. Redeploy this new Branch (even without changes)
3. All cubes now become Unprocessed (and deployed seemed to take longer than normal)

Comment: Which version of Analysis Services are you using and confirming this is a multidimensional vs tabular cube?

Comment: 2012 BI edition. This is a multidimensional solution.

Comment: Is the environment the same on Prod and Test? What's the option you used for process?

Comment: Yes, same environment (PROD). The option used for the process doesn't matter.. as it should never get into an unprocessed state in the first place (the crux of my question).

Comment: Does it occur if you redeploy from master branch?

Answer (score -1):

Try to go to the Warehouse Control Web Service, and check the Processing Status, then manually process the data warehouse relational database by following article [Manually Process the Data Warehouse and Analysis Services Cube for Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube).

To access the Warehouse Control Web Service:

1. Log on to the application-tier server.
2. Open Internet Explorer, type the following string in the Address bar, and then press ENTER:

-

```
http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx
```

If manually process Data Warehouse doesn't work, try to rebuild the data warehouse by following article [Rebuild the Data Warehouse and Analysis Services Cube](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/rebuild-data-warehouse-and-cube).

Comment: This has no relevance to my question

Comment: Do you mean the TFS cube doesn't process well? If yes, you can try the manual process.

Comment: I'm not sure what a TFS cube is. I am talking about my cubes that I have created in Analysis Services. I am using TFS only for source control.

Comment: It seems your issue is not related to TFS, correct? I was misleading by your tag, sorry.

Comment: Well I think it has something to do with TFS. Whenever I branch my project in TFS, this is where the issue comes about so I think TFS might be doing something funny like resetting GUID's or database ID's or something in the source files which make the Analysis Services Server believe this is a new project and as such recreate the database or something similar.

Comment: Could you provide detailed steps to reproduce this issue?